# Alternative to hardcoding usernames and passwords

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, security, razor

I am writing an MVC4 app using C# Razor and all that great stuff. It has full login and password along with an extra 2 questions required before the user can login.

Before I enabled the login feature several months back, it was a dream, I just start the app on the page I was interested in, and it loads away allowing me to instantly see my results.

Occasionally I would start on the wrong page and god forbid I might have to do an extra click or two to get to the right page. I considered this bad enough.

Now that I have enabled the login and since done several modifications to the code, it has been through the testing department, and out to the big bad world. I am not allowed to disable it again.

My alternative was to essentially hardcode the testing username and password and pin with the other default values required and then remove them upon release. Thank god for testing...I actually left them hardcoded once. This was enough to teach me the lesson never to do it again.

However, I start my application literally without exaggeration possibly hundreds (although it feels like thousands) of times a day and every single time I have to fill in this dreaded login form. this is extremely unproductive and really uses up a lot of my time. It actively encourages me to do bad programming habits of changing several things at once and then testing. A road I don't want to start down.

My question: Is there an alternative to this hardcoding practice that will let me get back my productivity?

Please don't suggest allowing the browser to remember the details. I tried, the problem is that my app must be cross browser and platform compatible which means it not only has to run in windows browsers (which has enough variation in themselves), but also on tablets, phones and even lunix and macs. So relying on the browser to remember the details is simply not an option.

Any suggestions.

Based on suggestions below I decided to explore the web/user.config route, here are my attempts so far which are not working.

Model:

```
public class LogOnModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    [StringLength(255, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 8)]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    [StringLength(255, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Controllers:

```
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        LogOnModel model = new LogOnModel(); 
        model.UserName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserName"];
        model.Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"];

        return View("Login");
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        model.UserName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserName"];
        model.Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"];
        //I am aware that this will presently overwrite the incoming model if it exists.
        //I am just trying to get something work here and I will surround it with an if afterward.

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
          ... Other code here
        }
          ... Other code here (there are a variety of returns this is a long method with lots of checks
    }
```

View:

@model YeatsClinical.PatientPortal.Web.Models.LogOnModel

```
...Lots of other code...
@Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.UserName,  new { @class = "m-wrap placeholder-no-fix", @placeholder="Username"})
...Lots of other code...
I didn't bother trying the password yet, I just wanted to get one thing working first.
```

Web.Config:

```
<appSettings file="user.config">
```

User.Config

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="UserName" value ="someone@somewhere.com"/>
    <add key="Password" value ="password"/>
</appSettings>
```

There are no longer any web/user.config errors or any build errors. It just loads a nicely formatted textbox with the placeholder text as before. So where am I going wrong. Thanks again everyone.

Comment: Are you using the MembershipProvider for your login functionality?

Comment: Its been so long since I was doing the login, is there a quick way I can find out for sure before I answer your question. Thanks.

Comment: "...and even Linux and Macs." shudder! :D

Comment: On a more serious note, your question is really broad without seeing your current attempts / code. In any case, something like [using SlowCheetah](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SlowCheetahWebconfigTransformationSyntaxNowGeneralizedForAnyXMLConfigurationFile.aspx) or [`#if DEBUG`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk.aspx) may be a simple way to do the trick?

Comment: @Jeroen I like this suggestion...I'll give it a try. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your login details in your local web.config file. Your code will look for the config values, and if there, will auto-fill them in for you. You can leave this code in when you deploy - since those values are not in the config file in production, you won't have to worry about it running there.

Or you can put them in a separate config file, like `user.config`, and reference that in your main config. Your `user.config` file will never be published. Just make sure your deployment practice doesn't bring this file in.

Web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings file="user.config">
    <!-- put your normal config values here -->
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

user.config (only your local machine - not in source control, and not on the server)

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="defaultUser" value ="someUser"/>
  <add key="defaultPassword" value ="somePassword"/>
</appSettings>
```

Another alternative might be to use conditional compilation, assuming you're in debug mode locally and release in release mode.

```
#if DEBUG
    PopulateTheUserCredentials();
#endif
```

Comment: So if I was using git, I should put the user.config in the gitIgnore file. for other source control, do the equivalent. Is this right.

Comment: Yep, SVN and Mercurial have similar concepts. I'm not sure about TFS or some of the other ones.

Comment: thanks, I will give this a bash and let you know. If it works as well as I hope, you have the accepted answer prize! :)

Comment: Are the Keys here the names of the html controls. If not how does visual studio know which text boxes to add the values to? Where also do I put the #if DEBUG... Is it in account controller? thanks again.

Comment: Now when I add this file (even before I add the <appSettings> content, I get an error pop up...Unable to start debugging on the web server. The web server is not configured correctly.

Comment: The keys are just regular config keys, so you'd still have to read them and put them in your code somewhere - in your controller, assuming you have a `UserModel` as your model, then `return View(new UserModel { UserName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["defaultUser"], Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["defaultPassword"] });`. This would send an empty model to your login page normally, but if those entries were found, it would pre-populate them, assuming you're using normal `@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.UserName)` controls on your view.

Comment: The `#if DEBUG` would be in your code as well. So same deal there - you can put it in your controller, and create a fully-populated `UserModel` if you're in debug mode, or an empty `UserModel` if you're not, then put that one into your view.

Comment: Regarding your error, usually that error means you've got invalid XML, so just check to make sure everything is valid. The example I provided works for me, so I'm guessing it's probably just a typo somewhere in your files.

Comment: I'll update my question a bit to show some code I am using. This should be working, but for some reason its not. Perhaps you can offer suggestions here. thanks again.

Comment: For your GET method, you forgot to put the model into the view: `return View(model);` or `return View("Login", model);` (either will work). For your POST method, you really don't need to do anything there - assuming the GET works, then the dummy user and password will be posted, so your `model` will always be either your dummy data, or real data - you should never have to read the config file from there.

Comment: Almost there...You have won the accepted answer anyway... One last question. It works when I use @Html.TextBoxFor for the password. The correct password actually appears. But obviously I want to use @Html.Password/For But when I change it to this, it doesn't work. any ideas why?

Comment: I believe that's a security feature - forgot about that. Looks like you can get around it by manually populating the value: `@Html.PasswordFor(x => x.Password, new { value = Model.Password })`

Comment: That's brilliant. This is a question I can use for reference in the future. Thanks again for all your help. On this, I'm voting up all your comments just cause you deserve the points for it. Thanks Joe.

Comment: For extra brownie points! You wouldn't know how I can make it click the login button too by any chance! :D

Comment: That one you can do with simple javascript - don't worry about the button, just submit the form directly: `document.getElementById("frmLogin").submit();` - just put that at the bottom of your view in a `script` tag, or you can put it in `document.ready` or whatever you might have hooked up to the page load. Just make sure you've given the form an id when you create it, like `@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "frmLogin" }))`. You'll just need to check to see if your model is pre-filled (you can check the model, or look at the textboxes, or however you want).